# Closure function argument

Tags: php, события, замыкания

У меня есть метод класса, который обновляет ценовые предложения товара:

```
public function updatePrices(int $productId, array $arPrices, ?Closure 
    $beforeUpdate, ?Closure $afterUpdate) : void 
{
    # update ..
}
```

Возникла потребность, в некоторых случаях выполнять какие-то действия до и после выполнения кода обновления цены.
Хотелось бы это реализовать через `callback`. 
т.е. методу нужно 2 дополнительных параметра, в которые можно будет передавать анонимную функцию и в этих функциях должен быть доступ к `$productId` и `$arPrices`.

Т.е. 2 события, `beforeUpdate` и `afterUpdate`, в `beforeUpdate` должна быть возможность модификации массива `$arPrices` или отмены обновления.

Как я себе это представляю (вероятно код неправильный):

```
public function updatePrices(int $productId, array $arPrices, 
    ?Closure $beforeUpdate, ?Closure $afterUpdate) : void 
{

    if($beforeUpdate !== null) {
        $modifyArPrices = $beforeUpdate($productId, $arPrices);
        if($modifyArPrices == null) { # отменяем обновление цен
            return;
        }
        $arPrices = $modifyArPrices; # Возвращаем модицифированный массив цен
    }

    # update ..

    if($afterUpdate !== null) {
        $afterUpdate($productId, $arPrices);
    }

}
```

При необходимости пишу так:

```
$this->updatePrices(1, ["BASE_PRICE" => 123], 
   function (int $productId, array $arPrices) : ?array {

    # Выполняю какие-то действия, при необходимости изменяю и возвращаю массив $arPrices
    # или
    # return null; # для того, чтобы отменить изменения цен

}, null);
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как будет выглядеть рабочий код. Как это делается? И как решаются подобные задачи правильным образом, с точки зрения архитектуры?

Comment: массив по ссылке-то передавайте. а так не ясно в чем вопрос, код не работает, или что? так примерно и делается, как написано.

Comment: согласен, как-то так и делается. Хотя я бы предпочёл требовать тип callable чем явный closure